# Excel "SMALL" "IF" another row is not blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula

I try not to ask for help like this but this one is screwing my noodle.

I have a costing spread sheet that I have managed to manipulate to give me a monthly cost role up (if exists) VS part number. Part numbers column c, months row 3.

On another sheet I'm trying to list the part numbers next to the cost role up and relevant date (each part number may have multiple entries)

I just need to do a "SMALL" for the "date" row (Row 3) on my costing sheet "IF" the "correct part number row" (or a fresh MATCH/VLOOKUP for the part number) has data in it. Or some how have the small return the Column INDEX number. I could then use INDEX to return the correct date and value using SMALL and Column B (the number of costs per part number, so if there are 3 instances that column currently list 1,2,3 before starting the next part number)

So close..... but this last bit is a struggle. Its a shame SMALL cant return INDEX Column numbers.

Does anyone know how to get a "SMALL" to lookup a row (based on a column search criteria) and check if the column has data, if so include the that column header in the "SMALL"

Update...

Thanks for your comments. I've stripped out the problem into a separate sheet to make it a little clearer. (I'll upload if possible).

I've also completed the rest of the excel to show the whole process. In doing so I've discovered Headers are automatically converted to text and so added a column to work around this using "DATEVALUE".

The goal is to list the number of costs related to a part number so.... if 500111 has had a cost role up in 3 different months it will list them in the cost report. So.... part number, relevant column "date" from "Cost data" sheet and relevant cost (@that part number @ that date). if I can get a list of dates from "Cost Data" columns and put them in Column D "Costing date (text)" next to the relevant part number i should be sorted. I've highlighted the column in red on the new screen shots.

[Cost Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPO84.png)

[Cost Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW1Ok.png)
lines highlighted in yellow just to show they are empty

Edit:

Almost there for anyone else trying this

=INDEX($B$5:$J$5,,SMALL(IF($B$6:$J$6>0,COLUMN($B$6:$J$6)),3))

I just need to figure out how to define a variable "ROW" within a SMALL(IF statement. I should then be able to reference the correct table row number (which I already have).

Anyone know how to put a variable ROW or COLUMN reference in a SMALL formula?

Comment: So, what result do you expect from given screenshot? You do not have any date in costing sheet. How you will understand which one is correct row number? You have 500 in 5 row, then which one you are trying to match? In row 3 where do you want to see your expected result?

Comment: I'll update the original question as I'm limited to comment length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not understand the problem fully.
But like this you can have a variable Row in the small formula:

```
=SMALL($A$4:$A$10;ROWS($C$4:C4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've played with it for a few more days and come up with "AGGREGATE(15,6," Then put a range reference within the formula. (basically i think the same as your suggesting but using AGGREGATE to return the column number. I'm sure there are prettier ways of doing this but I've finally managed to get the results I need.